# Doctrine AnnotationRegistry registerLoader replacement

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

To setup Symphoy Annotation based Routing I have this line

```
AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader([$loader, 'loadClass']);
```

It works fine but is a deprecated method:

```
 * @return void
 *
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
 *
 * @deprecated this method is deprecated and will be removed in doctrine/annotations 2.0
 *             autoloading should be deferred to the globally registered autoloader by then. For now,
 *             use @example AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader('class_exists')
 */
public static function registerLoader(callable $callable)
```

From that I do not understand what I should use instead.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 3):

AnnotationRegistry is deprecated and will be removed in doctrine/annotations 2.0, but for now it is still required.

If you already have an auto-loader set up, the simple workaround that they are suggesting is to set up AnnotationRegistry by passing in 'class_exists', which is a [php callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) function that simply checks if the class exists and returns true/false.

```
AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader('class_exists');
```